# load html with URL with added parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to load an html file and have paramaters passed on to the url as the page is loading?

Lets say an app loads index.html. Is there a way for the URL to become index.html?locale=ru instead of index.html?

Of course, this is easy if you can just click from somewhere but I would like the parameters to be added to the url "onload".

I was thinking of something like this maybe:

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.location.href= '?parameter1&parameter2'
}
```

Comment: If you do it this way, it will keep reloading, try to add something similar to `if (window.location.href.indexOf("?parameter1&parameter2") == -1)`

Comment: You would have better to explain what is your expected behaviour of appending query string to current URL? Why do you need that? The [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) could be what you are looking for but i have a doubt...

Comment: @A.Wolff What I need is for the app to load with index.html?parameter1 instead of index.html. The reason for this is the app using metadata and this takes the user to a specific location.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly:

```
window.location.replace("index.html#parameter1#parameter2");
```